# How to overcome IN clause issue in oracle

Tags: oracle

i am updating a table called `table2` from `table1` on column name `Active_status`.But the problem the result contains more than 1000.How to overcome this issue.I am using this query in a c# application.I heard we can use temp table ,if so how can i use or is there any better way.followingis my query

```
UPDATE table2
SET Active_status = 'N',
 MODIFIED_DATE    = SYSDATE
    WHERE t2_SLNO    IN
      (SELECT t2_SLNO
      FROM table2
      LEFT JOIN table1
      ON table2.t2_NAME       = table1.t1_NAME
      WHERE table1.t1_NAME IS NULL
      )
    AND Active_status <> 'N';
```

**EDIT**
I am doing this modification everday.By using a merge.But there are situations like table2 contain some dead data which i want to make status 'N' since the source of table1 and table2 is a remote database which is exposed by some other team.So thought of to do this work after my existing MERGE operation

Comment: Have a look at [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm); maybe it could solve it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# or .NET

Comment: @Aleksej i didn't get you.I am already using Merge for another case in order to update and insert for table1 and table1.What you are saying is i can use the same merge in order to achieve this??

Comment: You still haven't said what the **problem** is!

Comment: @Aleksej and all.I am doing this modification everday.By using a merge.But there are situations like table2 contain some dead data which i want to make status 'N' since the source of table1 and table2 is a remote database which is exposed by some other team

Comment: The 1000 limit is for a list of values (e.g. `x IN (1, 2, 3, ...)`), it does not apply for the subquery syntax you are using. So what is the problem, exactly? Using `not exists` would be simpler and quicker though.

Comment: With the statement in your question you do **not** have any "issue" with the `IN` clause. What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: i will go with @sagi second answer, since merge is deterministic cannot go with that.i put a word with sagi in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @aleksej suggested, you can use MERGE:

```
MERGE INTO table1 t
USING table2 s
ON(t.t1_NAME = s.t2_NAME)
WHEN NOT MATCHED UPDATE SET Active_status = 'N',
                            MODIFIED_DATE = sysdate 
WHERE t.Active_status <> 'N'
```

And you can change you update to work like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t
SET t.Active_status = 'N',
    t.MODIFIED_DATE = sysdate
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 s
                 WHERE t.t1_NAME = s.t2_NAME)
  AND t.Active_status <> 'N'
```

Comment: Why not put the Active_status <> 'N' in the ON?

Comment: Because MERGE won't allow to update a column that is in the ON clause. @Frisbee

Comment: You gave two sections and i am confused now ,one Merge and one Update

Comment: Both should do exactly the same, I just gave you two options @peter

Comment: Sorry ,my question was little wrong.I want to update table2 not not table1.i modified my question

Comment: @sagi you Update statement works ,but Merge throwing errors Missing keyword

Comment: @sagi i think merge is deterministic ,we canot update same row multiple time.Since i have updation task only , i will go with your second one.Are you okey??

Comment: It's missing a `then`, but `when not matched` can only insert anyway; `when matched` can only update, you can't mix them ([syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#BGBBBIDF)). The update with `not exists` seems like the correct way to do this.